# How to assert the value selected before is displayed in result summary page?

Tags: cypress

I have a web form which i want to use cypress to validate the data input is displayed at summary page after submission.

How do I use cypress to assert them?

```
Example:
Q1: ticked A
Q2: text abc

Result summary page:
Assert: 
Q1: A
Q2: text abc
```

AFTER RESULT:

```html
<div id="js-app" class=""><div data-reactroot=""><div class="_2nhBPjgwBzEAq_Q4AkjQz9"><div class="digital-service-standards dss-header sticky-header-enabled"><div class="sticky-header-wrapper sticky-header-enabled navbar-fixed"><div class="usads-masthead"><div class="usads-container" id="usads-navbar-container"><div class="row"><div class="col has-text-centered-touch"><a class="masthead-link" href="https://www.test.usa/" target="_blank" alt="A usa bond Agency Website"><span class="usads-icon usads-icon-usa-crest" title="test.usa"></span><span class="is-text">A usa bond Agency Website</span></a></div></div></div></div><nav class="navbar is-transparent"><div class="usads-container sticky-header-enabled"><div class="usads-navbar-brand" id="usads-test1-header-logo"><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/" class="navbar-item hidden-lg hidden-md sticky-header-enabled"><img class="test1-logo-mobile" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,++==" alt="Business g1 Portal"></a><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/" class="navbar-item hidden-xs hidden-sm sticky-header-enabled"><h1><img class="test1-logo-desktop" src="./SAVED_files/411121072cba44bf8e81534bd8565de5.svg" alt="Business g1 Portal"></h1></a><div class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="mainnav-1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div></div><div id="mainnav-1" class="navbar-menu"><div class="navbar-start" id="usads-navbar-start"><a class="navbar-item usads-mobile-search-item hidden-lg hidden-md"><div class="usads-mobile-search-bar field has-addons"><div class="control has-icons-left is-expanded"><input type="text" class="input is-fullwidth" id="search-box-mobile" title="search" name="query" placeholder="What are you looking for?" value=""><span class="icon is-left"><i class="usads-icon usads-icon-search is-size-5 search-bar"></i></span></div></div></a><a class="navbar-item hidden-lg hidden-md mobile-user-info-navbar-item"><div class="navbar-item" id="mobile-user-info-item"><div class="username-tag"><div class="username">tester</div><span class="role-info role-acceptor user-roles"><a>Acceptor</a></span><span class="company-name">IDA usa LIMITED usa BRANCH</span></div></div></a><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/dashboard" id="usads-nav-start" alt="Dashboard" class="navbar-item is-active">My g1</a><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/who_we_are" id="usads-nav-start" alt="About us" class="navbar-item">Who we are</a><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/how_it_works" alt="How it works" class="navbar-item">How it works</a><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/news" alt="News updates" class="navbar-item">News</a><a href="https://www.fa.test.usa/test1/apps/Fcd_faqmain.aspx" target="_blank" alt="Frequently asked questions" class="navbar-item">FAQ</a><a class="navbar-item logout"><div id="logout-button"><span>LOG OUT</span></div></a></div><div class="navbar-end" id="usads-navbar-end"><!-- react-text: 51 --><!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 52 --><!-- /react-text --><div class="navbar-item" id="user-info-item"><div class="username-tag"><div class="username">tester</div><span class="role-info role-acceptor user-roles"><a>Acceptor</a></span><span class="company-name">IDA usa LIMITED usa BRANCH</span></div></div></div></div></div></nav><div class="usads-container usads-search-bar is-fluid is-hidden-touch is-marginless hide"><div class="row is-gapless"><div class="col"><div class="field has-addons padding--sm"><div class="control is-right has-icons-left is-expanded padding--bottom--sm"><input type="text" title="search" class="input is-fullwidth is-borderless is-shadowless" id="search-box-desktop" name="query" placeholder="What are you looking for?" value="" autocomplete="off"><span class="icon is-left"><i class="usads-icon usads-icon-search is-size-5 search-bar"></i></span></div><div class="control"><a id="usads-search-button" role="button" tabindex="0" href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/g1/3SUwLbAp75qEWM8VCjLSmzqK/form/eligibility#" aria-label="Search" class="usads-button search-text padding--left padding--right"> Search</a></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="_2fwYxZEoTAa2o7rHUPuhRo"><div class="_3KFk7ULnHvFKHfd0A-n1vE"><div class="KK4WvVdpef8pgVCbod2hr _3mMusaMJNW0flNan3gYXDqZ _25Zwih1CK6Ay_SOJ75fwJr"><div class="test1-sidebar"><ul class="nav nav-sidebar sidebar-menu"><a class="back-title-container"><svg class="back-arrow" x="0px" y="0px" width="14px" height="14px" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><g><path data-color="color-2" d="M14,16c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.3l-6-7c-0.3-0.4-0.3-0.9,0-1.3l6-7c0.4-0.4,1-0.5,1.4-0.1 c0.4,0.4,0.5,1,0.1,1.4L9.3,8l5.4,6.3c0.4,0.4,0.3,1-0.1,1.4C14.5,15.9,14.2,16,14,16z"></path><path d="M8,16c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.3l-6-7c-0.3-0.4-0.3-0.9,0-1.3l6-7c0.4-0.4,1-0.5,1.4-0.1c0.4,0.4,0.5,1,0.1,1.4 L3.3,8l5.4,6.3c0.4,0.4,0.3,1-0.1,1.4C8.5,15.9,8.2,16,8,16z"></path></g></svg><span class="back-text">Back to testing Actions</span></a><li class="active"><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/g1/3SUwLbAp75qEWM8VCjLSmzqK/form/eligibility" class="active"><i><svg class="nc-icon outline" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g transform="translate(0, 0)"><line class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="10" y1="4" x2="22" y2="4" stroke-linejoin="miter"></line><line class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="10" y1="12" x2="22" y2="12" stroke-linejoin="miter"></line><line class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="10" y1="20" x2="22" y2="20" stroke-linejoin="miter"></line><rect class="icon-color-1" x="2" y="2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="4" height="4" stroke-linejoin="miter"></rect><rect class="icon-color-1" x="2" y="10" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="4" height="4" stroke-linejoin="miter"></rect><rect class="icon-color-1" x="2" y="18" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="4" height="4" stroke-linejoin="miter"></rect></g></svg></i><span class="menu-text">Eligibility</span><div class="sidebar-label"><span></span></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/g1/3SUwLbAp75qEWM8VCjLSmzqK/form/contact_info"><i><svg class="nc-icon outline" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g transform="translate(0, 0)"><path class="icon-color-1" fill="none" stroke="#444444" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M17,15l-3,3l-8-8l3-3L4,2 L1,5c0,9.941,8.059,18,18,18l3-3L17,15z" stroke-linejoin="miter"></path><path class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke="#444444" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M14,1 c4.971,0,9,4.029,9,9" stroke-linejoin="miter"></path><path class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke="#444444" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M14,5 c2.761,0,5,2.239,5,5" stroke-linejoin="miter"></path></g></svg></i><span class="menu-text">Contact Details</span><div class="sidebar-label"><span></span></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/g1/3SUwLbAp75qEWM8VCjLSmzqK/form/project"><i><svg class="nc-icon outline" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g transform="translate(0, 0)"><path class="icon-color-1" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M4,1h13c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2v18 c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H4" stroke-linejoin="miter"></path><rect class="icon-color-1" x="1" y="1" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="3" height="22" stroke-linejoin="miter"></rect><rect class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" x="8" y="5" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="7" height="4" stroke-linejoin="miter"></rect><line class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="8" y1="12" x2="15" y2="12" stroke-linejoin="miter"></line><line class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="8" y1="15" x2="11" y2="15" stroke-linejoin="miter"></line><line class="icon-color-1" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="21" y1="4" x2="21" y2="6" stroke-linejoin="miter"></line><line class="icon-color-1" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="21" y1="9" x2="21" y2="11" stroke-linejoin="miter"></line></g></svg></i><span class="menu-text">Proposal</span><div class="sidebar-label"><span></span></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/g1/3SUwLbAp75qEWM8VCjLSmzqK/form/project_impact"><i><svg class="nc-icon outline" x="0px" y="0px" width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g transform="translate(0, 0)"><rect class="icon-color-1" x="10" y="13" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="4" height="9" stroke-linejoin="miter"></rect><rect class="icon-color-1" x="2" y="17" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="4" height="5" stroke-linejoin="miter"></rect><rect class="icon-color-1" x="18" y="9" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="4" height="13" stroke-linejoin="miter"></rect><polyline class="icon-color-2" data-cap="butt" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="5,10 9,6 12,9 19,2 " stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt"></polyline><polyline class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" points=" 15,2 19,2 19,6 " stroke-linejoin="miter"></polyline></g></svg></i><span class="menu-text">Business Impact</span><div class="sidebar-label"><span></span></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/g1/3SUwLbAp75qEWM8VCjLSmzqK/form/project_cost"><i><svg class="nc-icon outline" x="0px" y="0px" width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g transform="translate(0, 0)"><path class="icon-color-1" data-cap="butt" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M21,15.1c1.2,0,2-0.7,2-2 s-1-1.5-1-1.5" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt"></path><path class="icon-color-1" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M15,9H9C7.8,6,5,7,5,7 l1,2.9c-1.2,0.7-2.1,1.8-2.6,3.1H1v5h2.8c0.7,1.2,1.8,2.2,3.2,2.7V23h3v-2h4v2h3v-2.3c2.3-0.8,4-3,4-5.7C21,11.7,18.3,9,15,9z" stroke-linejoin="miter"></path><line class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="11" y1="12" x2="15" y2="12" stroke-linejoin="miter"></line><circle class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="13" cy="3" r="2" stroke-linejoin="miter"></circle></g></svg></i><span class="menu-text">Cost</span><div class="sidebar-label"><span></span></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/g1/3SUwLbAp75qEWM8VCjLSmzqK/form/declaration"><i><svg class="nc-icon outline" x="0px" y="0px" width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g transform="translate(0, 0)"><line class="icon-color-2" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="3" y1="22" x2="21" y2="22"></line><path class="icon-color-1" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M13,12L9,8l6-6 c1.1-1.1,2.9-1.1,4,0l0,0c1.1,1.1,1.1,2.9,0,4L13,12z"></path><path class="icon-color-1" data-cap="butt" fill="none" stroke="#435e70" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M10,9l-6,6c-0.6,0.6-0.6,1.4,0,2 c0.6,0.6,1.4,0.6,2,0l6-6"></path><line class="icon-color-1" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="4" y1="17" x2="3" y2="18"></line><polyline class="icon-color-1" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="19,6 21,8 17,12 "></polyline></g></svg></i><span class="menu-text">Declare &amp; Review</span><div class="sidebar-label"><span></span></div></a></li></ul></div></div></div><div class="_1lL64NI9hS4wNQ_IwC0kEf"><div><div class="main"><div><h1 class="testing-title ">Market Readiness Assistance (MRA)</h1><div class=""><h2>Check Your Eligibility</h2></div><div class="helptext-wrapper"><div class="text-semibold success-helptext"><span class="mandatory-indicator">*</span> Mandatory field</div></div><div class="info-text-box margin-btm-md">“Applicant” or "you" refers to the company or business applying for this testing, e.g a sole proprietorship, partnership, limited liability partnership, or private limited company.</div><div class="form-horizontal test1-radio-group"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-xs-12"><div><label class="control-label test1-label">Is the applicant registered in usa?<span class="mandatory-indicator">&nbsp;*</span></label><!-- react-text: 173 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div><div class="controls test1-radio-text-format"><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="true" name="react-eligibility-usa_registered_check" id="react-eligibility-usa_registered_check-true"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">Yes</span></label><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="false" name="react-eligibility-usa_registered_check" id="react-eligibility-usa_registered_check-false"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">No</span></label><!-- react-text: 183 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div></div><!-- react-text: 184 --><!-- /react-text --><div class="form-horizontal test1-radio-group"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-xs-12"><div><label class="control-label test1-label">Is the applicant's group sales turnover less than or equal to S$100m or is the applicant's group employment size less than or equal to 200?<span class="mandatory-indicator">&nbsp;*</span></label><!-- react-text: 190 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div><div class="controls test1-radio-text-format"><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="true" name="react-eligibility-turnover_check" id="react-eligibility-turnover_check-true"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">Yes</span></label><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="false" name="react-eligibility-turnover_check" id="react-eligibility-turnover_check-false"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">No</span></label><!-- react-text: 200 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div></div><!-- react-text: 201 --><!-- /react-text --><div class="form-horizontal test1-radio-group"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-xs-12"><div><label class="control-label test1-label">Does the applicant have at least 30% <a class="test1-tooltip-link" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-content="&lt;p&gt; Shareholdings held by usa Citizen/Permanent Resident &lt;/p&gt;" data-original-title="" title=""> local equity</a>?<span class="mandatory-indicator">&nbsp;*</span></label><!-- react-text: 207 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div><div class="controls test1-radio-text-format"><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="true" name="react-eligibility-global_hq_check" id="react-eligibility-global_hq_check-true"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">Yes</span></label><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="false" name="react-eligibility-global_hq_check" id="react-eligibility-global_hq_check-false"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">No</span></label><!-- react-text: 217 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div></div><span><div class="eligibility-advice"><span>The applicant may not meet the eligibility criteria for this testing. Visit <a href="https://www.fa.test.usa/test1/apps/fcd_faqmain.aspx#FAQ_1111145" target="_blank">FAQ</a> page for more information on other bond g1.</span></div></span><div class="form-horizontal test1-radio-group"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-xs-12"><div><label class="control-label test1-label">Is the <a class="test1-tooltip-link" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-content="&lt;p&gt;Target market refers to the country you are expanding to&lt;/p&gt;" data-original-title="" title="">target market</a> that you are applying for a new market? A market is new if your company's revenue from there has not exceeded $100,000 for any of the last 3 years.<span class="mandatory-indicator">&nbsp;*</span></label><!-- react-text: 253 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div><div class="controls test1-radio-text-format"><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="true" name="react-eligibility-new_target_market_check" id="react-eligibility-new_target_market_check-true"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">Yes</span></label><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="false" name="react-eligibility-new_target_market_check" id="react-eligibility-new_target_market_check-false"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">No</span></label><!-- react-text: 263 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div></div><span><div class="eligibility-advice"><span>The applicant may not meet the eligibility criteria for this testing. Visit <a href="https://www.fa.test.usa/test1/apps/fcd_faqmain.aspx#FAQ_1111145" target="_blank">FAQ</a> page for more information on other bond g1.</span></div></span><div class="form-horizontal test1-radio-group"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-xs-12"><div><label class="control-label test1-label">Are <b>all</b> the following statements true for this project?<span class="mandatory-indicator">&nbsp;*</span> <ul> <li>The applicant has not started work on this project</li> <li> The applicant has not made any payment to any supplier, vendor, or third party prior to applying for this testing </li> <li> The applicant has not signed any contractual agreement with any supplier, vendor, or third party prior to applying for this testing </li> </ul></label><!-- react-text: 227 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div><div class="controls test1-radio-text-format"><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="true" name="react-eligibility-started_project_check" id="react-eligibility-started_project_check-true"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">Yes</span></label><label class="test1-radio"><input type="radio" value="false" name="react-eligibility-started_project_check" id="react-eligibility-started_project_check-false"><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="test1-label">No</span></label><!-- react-text: 237 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div></div><!-- react-text: 238 --><!-- /react-text --></div><div><div class="test1-btn-group"><div class="test1-btn-left"><!-- react-text: 242 --><!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 243 --><!-- /react-text --></div><div class="test1-btn-right"><button class="test1-btn test1-btn-save" id="save-btn" href="#">Save</button><a href="https://test1-qa.gatest-test.test/g1/3SUwLbAp75qEWM8VCjLSmzqK/form/contact_info"><button class="test1-btn test1-btn-next" id="next-btn">Next</button></a></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><!-- react-empty: 4 --></div></div>
```

Comment: please share the html for the summary page.

Comment: may i know which part of html you wanted to view? or i save the page as html is that good enough?

Comment: Please add the html code of both questions page and result summary page.

Comment: is there a function in cypress to use that assert the final value displayed at page after reload is remained as test script / user selected value?

Comment: @AlapanDas it is too many for me to paste in main post. how do i post the html file?

Comment: You don't have to paste the entire code. Just take the screenshot of the HTML source code for 1 Question with the options and then similarly for the summary page.

Comment: @AlapanDas I updated the main post with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235945/discussion-between-user12158726-and-alapan-das).